# Split WF instance

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a workflow service (.xamlx), type of flowchart workflow (WF4). WF service is hosted via IIS 7. I used request-response MEP. Service and operation contract are defined using Receive activities.
Workflow instance represents the request for training and contains candidates for the training. Training is multiphase and each phase ends with a meeting. My problem is if some candidate don't attend the meeting, he needs to go  back to a previous step in the workflow, while others go to the next phase.
How to split the instance in this case or what to do to support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like each student can have it's own part through the workflow independent of others. That suggests that each student should be a separate workflow instance.

Comment: Is it possible to clone an workflow instance, or create a new one with the necessary information and continue its execution from the corresponding point (activity).

Comment: There is no way to clone a worklfow and start executing somewhere in the middle. You would really need to model this in the worklfow and just start another one with some special startup parameter telling it to skip the first part.

Comment: Ok, tnx. I will try something like that. At first I was thinking of forking the path of execution, but it seems that the flowchart has a single path of execution.